# Making good use of ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations with separate assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Let's say that I have a Domain assembly that describes the domain model, and it has a class called product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have also another assembly that is the web application running with this domain model. Now I want to create a form to create new products and have some validation on the attributes. The easiest way to do this is to use DataAnnotations on the class. However this results in that the domain model now contains metadata about form validation, which is not a very clear separation of concerns.

It is possible to have the `MetadataType` attribute for the class but I see this as no better. Suddenly your domain model class has a dependency on the form validation metada class.

Another way is to create a `CreateProductForm` class and add the required attributes there, and do mapping between the classes. However this creates some overhead as you need to maintain these classes seperately and changes in one might break the other. It might be desirable in some scenarios to do that, but in some others it might just create extra work (imagine that you have an Address class, for example).

UPDATE: some people have suggested that I use AutoMapper for this, which I'm already aware of. AutoMapper just makes mapping simpler and easier, does not actually solve the problem of having to maintain two separate classes which will be almost identical. My preference would be to only create the form classes when there is a distinct need for it.

Is there a straightforward to declare the annotations within the web assembly, without creating unnecessary dependencies for the domain assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you have DataAnnotations on your domain classes. If there is something that is Required, then I think it's perfectly valid to mark it as required in the domain.

Other DataAnnotations such as StringLength, Range etc, all to me perfectly valid things to decorate your domain entities with.

Implementing IValidableObject is also a perfectly acceptable thing for domain object to do IMHO.

I wouldn't go putting UI stuff on them such as UIHint though or annoations describing the formatting of the property. That would be bad.

Normally I avoid displaying domain classes on the user interface, and use ViewModel classes with a mapping tool such as AutoMapper etc to map from one to the other. The ViewModel class has the annoations of the domain class with perhaps additional UI specific annotations.

Comment: Because it is mixing form validation logic with the domain model. The Required attribute takes an error message as a parameter as well, should this be part of the domain model?

Comment: @Can That a field is "required" isn't form validation logic, it's domain information The field is still required even if you're not looking at it on a form. That error message isn't required, though putting it there is pretty convenient. This issue reads like you're being unnecessarily strict in trying to deal with separation of concerns. The fact is that in reality things rarely work out so perfectly as they do in design pattern books.

Comment: @Tridus, I disagree. The Required field means the field is required for the form, it does not have to mean it is required for the domain model. Also as I said, why does it take an error message string as a parameter if it's domain information?

Comment: @Can Gencer: Is the fact a Comment entity *requires* a Post entity a domain condition or a UI condition? Is the fact that a Post entity *requires* a title a domain condition or a UI condition? The answer is both. In addition to UI validation, domain model validation is a good practice in the domain model, else you do not have defence in depth against dodgy inputs into your domain. The domain services should not blindly trust what is being given to them, and application validation is infinitely cleaner than database constraint violations.

Comment: @Xhalent, while I understand the value of what you say, I think the DataAnnotations in particular is typically aimed at UI validation and has very little use in actual domain validation. Domain Validation in my eyes would be at the setter methods or at constructor level, for example.

Comment: @can gencer: I think you need to question why you think data annotations are UI specific. Entity framework inspects these validators on saving, and Nhibernate has a number of similar validators based on attributes. These services are hardly UI centered. If you coded validators in setters, how would you validate something as required? The validation framework in data annotations works and I'd have be really convinced before reinventing this particular wheel. Cheers.

Comment: @Xhalent, I haven't used EF, so I think you have a point there. If something would be required in a domain sense, then it should be a parameter for the constructor for that object. I've always viewed them UI specific previously, I will see if I can make them fit into the picture in the domain model. I am using NHibernate, so having two separate validation layers on the same object would not be the cleanest solution.

Comment: This became the approach I went with finally, as I felt having DataAnnotations on my domain objects is better than duplicating all the fields in two different classes. I refactored my domain classes into having multiple components, which are shared across form classes where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to introduce coupling between your domain model and your views, you should go for the CreateProductForm class way.

Depending on your project size/requirements, you're going to have to separate your view model from your domain sooner or later. Suppose you're using the DisplayName attribute : are you going to tag your domain entities ?

Using a tool like AutoMapper simplifies greatly the mapping process.

Comment: Yes I know about mapping, however as I said this creates some additional overhead and I would like to only do mapping when it is necessary (i.e. the domain model and the form differ from each other in a significant way)

Answer (score 0):

As mathieu and XHalent state you should use a CreateProductForm (or a CreateProductFormViewModel) along with [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and create attribues that automap the model to the viewmodel for the action.

That way all the form validation goes on your view model and all the data validation (related to the database) goes in your domain model.

In Silverlight and WPF it is called the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)  and a lot of people who do asp.net mvc recommend it.

In my current project I am also using it with Automapper.  All my views have an associated view model that is a flattened version of the domain model specific to that view.

I think [this](http://mhinze.com/2009/07/06/automapper-in-nerddinner/) was the example I used (It's the one I still have bookmarked anyway. but this [one](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) linked in the first one seems better.)
Using the attribute means that you return the domain object from your action in the controller and the automap attribute maps the domain object to your viewmodel automatically.

Doing this should give you the seperation you are looking for.

Comment: I am fully aware of this approach. However it gets a problematic, say when I have a Person class, which has a member called Address, which has a lot of properties such as Street, Country and so on. If I create an extra class for this as well, suddenly I have a lot of repetition in the code . It would have been nice to be able to declare the metadata for the Address class in a different way.

Comment: The repetition is worth it.  it means that your presentation layer is not dependant on your data layer.  Without the viewmodel you data layer permiates from the database up to yor presentation layer.  The MVVM means that the data layer stops at your controllers.